# Angular change Interface definition when I use as with promise

Tags: angular, typescript, interface, angular6

I have predefined properties in interface as below:

```
export interface User {
  userID : number;
  userName : string;
  userAge : string;
}
```

Also, I have service which returns some dummy data from some dummy REST api.

```
getUsers(){
    return this.http.get("https://fakerestapi.azurewebsites.net/api/Authors").toPromise();
  }
```

and in component I am consuming this service and convert data to userlist as per below code:

```
 _service.getUsers().then(i => { this.userList = i as User[]; console.log(this.userList) });
```

as you can see, I used 'AS' to convert response to my respective user[] array.

**ISSUE:**
dummy REST api retruns following data

```
{
    "ID": 1,
    "IDBook": 1,
    "FirstName": "First Name 1",
    "LastName": "Last Name 1"
  }
```

and user class doesn't have property of ID, IDBook etc. still when I check console, it automatically change the definition of User class and shows all the data although properties are not matched.

Link:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pryy3f?file=src%2Fapp%2Fappservice.service.ts

As per my understanding only match properties should be displayed not all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In typescript `as` keyword is not a type casting but a type assertion. So what is happening is this:

- you ask for a `User[]`
- you receive a `JSON object[]`
- the `JSON object[]` is transformed into a User's interface array (look at what is an interface in typescript)
- the compiler accept `this.userList` as a `User[]` but it is only a type assertion

So using `as` keyword is redundant in this case and completely useless.

A type assertion is only useful for autocompletion and other similar things that are elaborated at compile time. But it is not a real cast. So when you execute your code `this.userList` is always a `JSON Object[]`

If you need real User objects you should do something like this:

```
_service.getUsers().then(i => { 
    this.userList = i.map(u => new User(u)); 
    console.log(this.userList) 
});
```

Obviously you should define a constructor into your `User` class

**EDIT**

Looking at your Authors file I can see you are using an xml syntax that is converted into an array treated as Object. For this reason map operator fails. I have changed a bit your code

**User**

```
export class User {
  userID : number;
  FirstName : string;
  userAge : string;

  constructor()
  constructor(u: User)
  constructor(u?: User) {
     this.userID = u && u.userID || -1;
     this.FirstName = u && u.FirstName || '';
     this.userAge = u && u.userAge || '';
  }

  clone(): User {
    // TODO CLONE USER
    return new User();
  }
}
```

**AppComponent**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AppserviceService } from './appservice.service';
import { User } from './user';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  private userList: User[] = [];
  constructor(private _service: AppserviceService) {
    _service.getUsers().then(i => {  
      for (let c=0; c<10; c++) {
        let u = new User(i[c]);
        this.userList.push(u);
      }

      console.log('this.userList', this.userList);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code in stackblitz link. I created the constructor into user class. but I am getting following error "TypeError: user_1.User is not a constructor
TypeError: user_1.User is not a constructor". can you help to explain me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: have you added the constructor into User class?

Comment: do you need promises for some reason or i can update it to Observable?

Comment: I need to use promise, I can do with Observable but need a resolution with Promise

Comment: constructor is not working as per you said and getting error. can you edit stackblitz link?

Comment: Ok. I got your point. I need to use class instead of interface

Answer (score 0):

Defining an interface with Typescript has absolutely no effect on generated Javascript code, since interfaces do not exist in Javascript. You can figure it out by playing with the [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html). Interfaces are just something that help you (as a developer) and your team detecting errors at compilation time.

So the object you return from HTTP will always be as is, regardless of the interface you apply to it, because there is no such thing as interface or cast in Javascript.